# Using or in Media Query?

Tags: css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobile.css" media="screen and (max-height: 500px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobile.css" media="screen and (orientation:portrait)" />
```

I've got the above media query to target portrait and window height < 500 users, is there a way to consolidate them into one link tag using OR in media query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use , for OR operator.

Reference : [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

So, your code will be :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobile.css" media="screen and (max-height: 500px), screen and (orientation:portrait)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relevant section of the [MDN article on media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries#comma-separated_lists).

Just combine them with a comma:

```
media="screen and (max-height: 500px), screen and (orientation: portrait)"
```